# can't access kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

i followed this guide [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/) to install a kubernetes cluster and i have no error, but i can't access kubernetes-Dashboard

I did
`kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`
and when i go to https://192.168.11.20/ui is nothing there

how can i access the dashboard?

some additional information

```
[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS    AGE
kubenode1   Ready     6h
kubenode2   Ready     6h

[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get pods
No resources found.

[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl describe svc kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
Name:           kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:      kube-system
Labels:         app=kubernetes-dashboard
Selector:       app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:           NodePort
IP:         10.254.81.213
Port:           <unset> 80/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 31785/TCP
Endpoints:      <none>
Session Affinity:   None
No events.

[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   1         0         0            0           6h

[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl --namespace=kube-system get ep kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   ENDPOINTS   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   <none>      6h

[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://kubeMaster:8080

[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get ns
NAME          STATUS    AGE
default       Active    6h
kube-system   Active    6h

[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get ep
NAME         ENDPOINTS            AGE
kubernetes   192.168.11.20:6443   6h
```

Answer (score 9):

192.168.0.0/16 is a private IP range, meaning you need to be within the cluster's network to access it.

The easiest way to access your service outside the cluster is to run `kubectl proxy`, which will proxy requests to your localhost port 8001 to the Kubernetes API server. From there, the apiserver can proxy to your service:

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard

Comment: I did that but i still get  "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. It looks like you don't have any dashboard pods running. My guess is the pods are crashing for some reason. Try `kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system`, and then `kubectl describe --namespace=kube-system pod $POD`, where `$POD` is the name of the dashboard pod. If that doesn't work, try describe on the deployment to see any events associated with it.

Comment: I don't have any pod [root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system
No resources found.

Comment: Did you try describing the deployment? `kubectl describe deployment --namespace=kube-system kubernetes-dashboard`

Comment: `[root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl describe deployment --namespace=kube-system kubernetes-dashboard
Name:   kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:  kube-system
CreationTimestamp: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 12:13:21 +0000
Labels:   app=kubernetes-dashboard
Selector:  app=kubernetes-dashboard
Replicas:  0 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:  RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds: 0
RollingUpdateStrategy: 1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:  kubernetes-dashboard-3203831700 (0/1 replicas created)
No events.`

Answer (score 6):

I know that this is old question, but we spent several hours when looked for solution. It was so silly...
Posting it here for next comers...

When you are starting proxy, and browsing to 127.0.0.1:8080/ui/, you are redirected to the following url:

http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy

This url in our case is opened as white empty screen.
The issue is that this url is missing slash at the end. When added, everething is working as a charm... :(

http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
kubectl proxy
```

Which will let you access the dashboard at:

```
localhost:8001
```

Answer (score 1):

1  used ssh connect master node and config ssh tunnel as below:

[ssh tunnel config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJmjr.png)

2  start kubectl proxy
[kubectl proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlmGp.png)

3 At localhost, used  http url access dashboard
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/about?namespace=default

Comment: Doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0):

To actually find pod with dashboard you should run

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --show-all`

or

`kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system`

From what we can see on your outputs you can either run `kubectl proxy` (already described) or just go to `http://{any_node}:31785`.

You have dashboard service with `Type: NodePort`, which means that it will be accessible on `NodePort` on any node in this cluster.

Comment: I don't have any pod                                                                      [root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --show-all
No resources found.

Comment: I need to have a pod with dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Its not actually running.  If it was, your "get deployment" results would return 1's instead of 0's.

try doing a `kubectl describe deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system` That will be the first step for your troubleshooting.  at the end of the results, it may have something in the events.

you may need to see what the logs are for the pod as well depending on the results of your deployment query.

Comment: [root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl describe deployment --namespace=kube-system kubernetes-dashboard  
Name:   kubernetes-dashboard  
Namespace:  kube-system  
CreationTimestamp: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 12:13:21 +0000  
Labels:   app=kubernetes-dashboard  
Selector:  app=kubernetes-dashboard  
Replicas:  0 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable  
StrategyType:  RollingUpdate  
MinReadySeconds: 0  
RollingUpdateStrategy: 1 max unavailable, 1 max surge  
OldReplicaSets:  <none>  
NewReplicaSet:  kubernetes-dashboard-3203831700 (0/1 replicas created)  
No events.

Comment: when you do a get pods, use the --all-namepace since its in the kube-system namespace. so its kubectl get pods --all-namespace

Comment: i don't have any pod running

Comment: [root@kubeMaster ~]#  kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
No resources found.

Comment: have you run through https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/walkthrough/ ?  try making just a pod and see what happens. 

Also, try checking docker to see if the containers were even created.

Comment: yes, i create a pod successful                                                      [root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx     1/1       Running   0          4h

Comment: but i still don't have a dashboard pod

Comment: i deleted and created again, now i have this

Comment: [root@kubeMaster ~]#  kubectl get po -o wide --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
default       nginx                                   1/1       Running            0          4h        172.30.97.2   kubenode2
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-3203831700-9f9s7   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m        172.30.97.3   kubenode2

Comment: [root@kubeMaster ~]# kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-3203831700-9f9s7 --namespace=kube-system
Using HTTP port: 9090
E0214 18:55:46.134422       1 config.go:275] Expected to load root CA config from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt, but got err: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory

Comment: if your using certs (whichi t appears to be) its not at that location.  put your ca cert there.

Comment: i'm not using any certificate this is a standard instalacion 
I only did what I was in this guide (https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/) 
Nothing else